# Exceptions: How to display which function caused the exception?

Tags: python, exception

I have a code block that looks like:

```
try:
    if x == 1:
        a()
    if x == 2:
        b()
    if x == 3:
        c()
except Exception:
    raise Exception("Problem in function")
```

Each of the functions `a()`, `b()`and `c()` are capable of having exceptions. Is there anyway I can raise an exception with a message that tells which function caused the exception.

I want to know if its possible here without using `try`, `catch` statements inside each of these functions separately.

Comment: Why are you catching the original exception at all?

Comment: Use the value of x to find out? Let the original error go instead of catching it and throwing a new one? Raise the new error _from_ the old one?

Comment: (There is a way to do this even if catching the original exception is correct - in fact, Python should *already be doing it for you*, although there's a better way manually - but it's very likely you shouldn't catch the original exception at all.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generic way to do which uses the [`traceback.extract_tb()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb) function to get a list of “pre-processed” stack trace entries which have a subset of what's in a [TracebackException](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#tracebackexception-objects) object in them from the most recent exception (this is the same information that's in tracebacks when they're display. The last entry contains information about the last function called (i.e. the most recent one) including its name.

```
import traceback

def a():
    pass

def b():
    raise RuntimeError('Oops!')

def c():
    pass


x = 2
try:
    if x == 1:
        a()
    if x == 2:
        b()
    if x == 3:
        c()
except Exception as exc:
    filename, lineno, funcname, text = traceback.extract_tb(exc.__traceback__)[-1]
    raise Exception(f"Problem in function {funcname}()") from exc
```

Here the output it displays:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "display-which-function-caused-the-exception.py", line 22, in <module>
    b()
  File "display-which-function-caused-the-exception.py", line 10, in b
    raise RuntimeError('Oops!')
RuntimeError: Oops!

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "display-which-function-caused-the-exception.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise Exception(f"Problem in function {funcname}()") from exc
Exception: Problem in function b()
```

Comment: for some reason im getting the following response, so looks like funcname cant be found? 
```raise Exception ("Problem in function {funcname}()") from e
Exception: Problem in function {funcname}()
``` Im expecting the function name to show up in the error response, cant figure out why this is showing in the response.

Comment: for in this case it always shows the last subfunciton, is there anyway to define that it only shows the function which I defined and not python-initial funcitons?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
import traceback
try:
    if x == 1:
        a()
    if x == 2:
        b()
    if x == 3:
        c()
except Exception as excp:
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()[:-3] + traceback.extract_tb(excp.__traceback__) 
    
    (filename, line, procname, text) = stack[-1]
    print (f" func {procname}")# 
   

    raise Exception("Problem in function")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Which part of the code is not compatible with Python3?

Comment: The `print` statements should have parentheses.

Comment: I just edit my code

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would think of is to try something like this:

```
try:
    if x == 1:
        a()
    if x == 2:
        b()
    if x == 3:
        c()
except Exception:
    raise Exception("Problem in function, x=%s"%x)
```

Now, when the exception is raised, you can see what the value of x was.

For something more detailed, perhaps something like this:

```
try:
    if x == 1:
        flabel = 'func_a'
        a()
    if x == 2:
        flabel = 'func_b'
        b()
    if x == 3:
        flable = 'func_c'
        c()
except Exception:
    raise Exception("Problem in function %s"%flabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too specific to your example, but I would in general try to refactor the code and make a specific note of which function is going to be executed.

```
if x == 1:
    func_name = "a"
    func = a
elif x == 2:
    func_name = "b"
    func = b
elif x == 3:
    func_name = "c"
    func = c

try:
    func()
except Exception:
    raise Exception(f"Problem in {func_name}")
```

You may be able to get rid of `func_name` and use `func.__name__` instead, as long as all three functions are being referred by their "original" name.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to use func._ _name_ _.

Comment: You literally just use it instead of `func_name`. `f'Problem in {func.__name__}'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a decorator function that wrapped the function of interest so that the information needed was available (this is a variation of @chepner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585652/355230)):

```
def decorator(func):
    wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global func_name
        func_name = func.__name__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def a():
    pass

@decorator
def b():
    raise RuntimeError('Uh Oh!')

@decorator
def a():
    pass


x = 2

try:
    if x == 1:
        a()
    if x == 2:
        b()
    if x == 3:
        c()
except Exception as exc:
    raise Exception(f"Problem in function {func_name}()")
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I am trying to learn decorators now to see if this can be implemented.  When you declare the decorator function in your answer, it is general one ?

Comment: The decorator shown is generic although it is hardcoded to update a global variable named `func_name`.